# CodeIgniter or Simple PHP , how to join a table with two colomns of another table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have a form with two select inputs. In each input there are products as options. Each visitor must select two products as their favorites. Their choice goes into a table named: `visitors_fav`

The structure of table is:

```
visitors_fav:
vis_ID    -   productID_1   -    productID_2
```

As you see i fetch the product IDs not their names and store them into the table.

I have another table named: `Products`, the structure is like:

```
Product_ID   -    Product_Name
```

How can I get the `Product_Name` for both `productID_1` & `productID_2` in a query?

(PHP Codeigniter active record is preferred, and also my database is mySQL)

Comment: Did you tried anything? You already got an answer and its good.Hope you can change them to CI active record.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you must join visitors_fav with Products two times to get the results you want. try the following query:

```
select vis_ID, prod1.Product_Name as Product_Name1, prod2.Product_Name as Product_Name2
from visitors_fav vis join Products as prod1 on vis.productID_1 = prod1.Product_ID 
                      join Products as prod2 on vis.productID_1 = prod2.Product_ID
```